# Java policy settings not working for FilePermission

Tags: java, java-5, javapolicy

Our Java policy file used to just be:

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I am trying to make our application more secure than just granting everything to everyone.  I have it working well except I am having troubles giving permission to files.

The error I currently get is:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission \\server.log write)
```

I have tried so many combinations of things, such as:

```
permission java.io.FilePermission "\\\\server.log", "write";
permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Temp\\logs\\server.log", "write";
permission java.io.FilePermission "\\server.log", "write";
permission java.io.FilePermission "${TEMP}${/}-", "write";
permission java.io.FilePermission "*", "read,write";
```

The only thing I can get it to work is using:

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I get the error "java.io.FileNotFoundException: \server.log (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)" when using (even when the files do exist):

```
permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "write";
```

Just wondering if anyone had any other ideas to try.  I don't really want to have to resort to granting all just to get the file permissions right, obviously I am missing something.

**EDIT:**

I just realized that maybe this is a clue in the log file:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,false) call failed.
```

Maybe I need some permissions for this specifically? Digging around Google now....

Comment: Hi, did u resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle documentation have some examples:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/spec/security-spec.doc3.html

```
permission java.io.FilePermission "myfile", "read,write";
permission java.io.FilePermission "/home/gong/", "read";
permission java.io.FilePermission "/tmp/mytmp", "read,delete";
permission java.io.FilePermission "/bin/*", "execute";
permission java.io.FilePermission "*", "read";
permission java.io.FilePermission "/-", "read,execute";
permission java.io.FilePermission "-", "read,execute";
permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read";

permission java.io.FilePermission "c:\\temp\\foo", "read,write,delete")
\\this one works for me
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is because you are trying to write to a file without permission to read it.

```
permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\folder\\*", "read, write";
```